# D3 force layout forceY does not map to range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to order my nodes vertically in D3 force layout using the `forceY()` property but I am failing to restrict the upper bound of my y axis. My canvas has height of 200px and I have 50 categories that I want to order and project onto plane that has 1000px height. I initially want to see the top 200px while the rest of the nodes can go out of sight on the bottom. I let the user pan there if needed.

I used `let y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 50]).range([0, 1000]);` combined with `d3.forceSimulation(nodes).force("y", d3.forceY().y(d => y_scale(d.category)))` I thought that would make the nodes to be naturaly drawn at 0 px and lower but it does not. The nodes are ordered based on the categories but the 0 category does not map to 0px but to say -400px which is out of sight on the top side.

Is there a way to make the `forceY` to truly map to the `[0, 1000]` range?

I know I can restrict the `y` of the nodes when drawn on the svg using something like `Math.max(0, d.y)` but that will only make all the nodes that would trail off on the top to be stacked at the 0 line.

Answer (score 1):

For categorical variables, you should use [`d3.scaleBand()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleBand) instead. That should be the main reason for the weird positioning:

```js
const fruits = ["Apple", "Apple", "Pear", "Pear", "Orange", "Grape"];
const data = fruits.map(d => ({
  x: 50,
  fruit: d
}));
const colours = ["Red", "Green", "Orange", "Purple"];
const unique = arr => arr.filter((d, i) => arr.indexOf(d) === i);

const yscale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(unique(fruits))
  .range([50, 150]);

const colour = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(unique(fruits))
  .range(colours);

const circle = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", 200)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("cx", d => d.x)
  .attr("cy", d => yscale(d.fruit))
  .attr("fill", d => colour(d.fruit));


var graphLayout = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(5))
    .force("x", d3.forceX(50))
    .force("y", d3.forceY().y(d => yscale(d.fruit)))
    .on("tick", ticked);

function ticked() {
  circle
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```